# Deshabilitar un select con jquery cuando un input no este vacio

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenos Días.

Lo he intentado con una funcion pero el detalle es que el input es de `readonly`, es decir, el usuario no puede escribir, el `input` es tipo text que se alimenta de un buscador, se trae un código y lo coloca en ese campo, e intentado colocándole `onchange` y nada.

¿Me podrían indicar con un ejemplo?
Gracias.

Mi codigo:

```html
<input type="text" name="txtnumsoldes" id="txtnumsoldes" size="30" readonly="" />
<a href="javascript: ue_catalogo('solicitud.php?tipo=REPDES');" title="Catalogo"><img src="../shared/imagebank/tools15/buscar.gif" alt="Buscar" width="15" height="15" border="0" class="false" ></a>

<select name='cmb' id='cmb'  onclick='ue_div()' style=width:350px>;
<option value='-' >---seleccione--- </option>;
```

FUNCION DONDE AL DARLE CLICK EL CODIGO LO PASA A MI FORMULARIO

```html
function ue_aceptar_reportedesde(ls_numsol)
{
 opener.document.formulario.txtnumsoldes.value=ls_numsol;
 //opener.document.formulario.cmb.value="";
 //opener.document.formulario.cmb.disabled=true;
 }
 close();
}
```

Lo que esta comentado fue lo que intente hacer pero en el formulario de busqueda me da error de "indefinido" ya que el cmb no existe en ese formulario, no se si me explique bien

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que has intentado?

Comment: lo he intentado con una funcion peroel detalle es q el input es de readonly,es decir, el usuario no puede escribir, el input es tipo text q se alimenta de un buscador, se trae un codigo y lo coloca en ese campo, e intentado colocandole onchange y nada

Comment: Podrías colocar lo que has intentado y comentarnos donde no esta funcionando como debería.

Comment: estimados ya lo pongo en el hilo general

Comment: lo q se requiere es q cuando en el input se detecte q hay caracter m deshabilite el select

Comment: se me occure tambien q lo oculte y que este vacio ese select

Comment: Da una vuelta por el [FAQ](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para que veas cómo funciona el sitio

Comment: ya lo edite estimado

Comment: pero si el *input* es *readonly* siempre va a estar habilitado el *select* por que siempre va a estar vacio

Comment: y d q manera podria deshabilitar el select? porq al darle buscar y seleccione un dato ya hay datos ahi, lo unico es q el usuario no puede tipear ahi

Comment: Edita tu pregunta añadiendo los detalles de tu problema para poder ayudarte. No queda claro lo que quieres hacer

Answer (score 0):

Creo que seria algo asi...

> ```
>  if ($('#txtnumsoldes').val()!='') {
>             $('#cmb').attr('disabled',true)
>         }
> ```

Comment: Hola Roberto, aunque esto puede responder a la pregunta expuesta, sería ideal que añadieras una pequeña descripción de lo que hace el código y de por qué resolvería el problema. Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: Okas gracias por la observación

Answer (score 0):

En este caso tendrás que consultar primero tu busqueda y despues verificar la respuesta de tu valor del input.

Estoy suponiendo que consultas por medio de ajax, el cual te retornara la respuesta de tu input, esa misma será la que medirá la longitud del escrito.

```js
function busqueda(){
  $.ajax({
    datatype: "json",
    type: "POST",
    url: 'busqueda',
    data: { objBuqueda: objBuqueda},
    success: function (respuesta) {
      $("#txtnumsoldes").val(respuesta);
      var bandera = respuesta.length > 0;
      if(bandera){
        $("#cmb").prop({ readOnly: true });
       }
       else{
        $("#cmb").prop({ readOnly: false });
       },
    error: function () { }
    });  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtnumsoldes" size="30" readonly/>

<select id='cmb'>
  <option value='-' >---seleccione--- </option>
  <option value='1' >Uno</option>
  <option value='2' >Dos</option>
  <option value='3' >Tres</option>
</select>
```

Comment: excelente tu respuesta, el detalle es q el input se alimenta a traves de un buscador, el input es readonly

Comment: A ver, creo que ya te entendí

Comment: ok, bueno mi consulta es a traves de otro formulario funciones pero es mas o menos grande el codigo, no es en ajax

Comment: Entiendo, pero aplica la lógica de la solución. Revisa la longitud del valor, si te fijas mido la respuesta, no el input desde el momento en que lo va cargar.

Comment: exactamente me diste una idea de medir la longitud, de gual forma, te coloque la funcion donde llama el resultado y lo pega en el input

Comment: yo coloco la longitud en la funcion q t comente pero esa funcion esta en otro formulario y no reconoce el select